# Google Sheets Ifs Statement: Only Counting One Logical Expression

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to set up a database and set up different alerts/flags if data is not entered in certain cells. For instance, if data is entered in cell one but not in cell two, I want one alert but if data is not entered in either, a different alert.

At the moment, I have tried to use this:

```
=IFS(C2="*", "Plant", E2="","Support")
```

Support is showing up correctly, but Plant is not.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=IF((A2<>"")*(B2<>""), "all good",
 IF((A2="") *(B2=""),  "both values missing",
 IF( A2="",            "A value missing",
 IF( B2="",            "B value missing", ))))
```

[image]